# How to provide path to image/logo file in html file in a tree structure

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my project.
I'm working on a university project based on Django and in fact we don't know HTML, CSS at all.
I have a small hierarchy of catalogs:

```
-> Project
  -> LibProject
    -> templates
      -> LibProject
        -> main.html
  -> images
    -> logo.png
```

There LibProject and images are in the same level.
I would like to add a logo.png via  inside main.html file.
I've tried  to get 3 directories up and then go to images/logo.png but it doesn't work.

PS: It has to be static image.

May you give me any sollution for this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: [django docs on static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files). In particular, check point 4 on where to store it.

Answer (score 0):

you should do some settings to before that :

1. add

```py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

to your settings.py

2. add

```py
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),#this is your static files dir 
]
```

to your settings.py

3. in your url.py file you should add this:

```py
urlpatterns = ["""your urls"""] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

for more details please read django doc :
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

Comment: Well, I see it. Thank you very much but I still have no idea how to improve image inside my code. Could you help me with this line also? I would be very glad.

Comment: {% load static %}
<img src="{% static "my_app/example.jpg" %}" alt="My image">

Comment: I get it but still if I write ../../../images/logo.png it doesn't work. Tried to other combinations without any good effect.

Comment: <img src="{% static '../../../images/logo.png' %}" alt="Logo"> doesn't work

Comment: "GET /static/images/logo.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1770
or   "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3039 and as you can expect, image is not seen on website

Comment: your path is an incorrect do you create a static folder?

Comment: Yes, I have created via New -> Directory and there I've put logo.png. Everything seems to be correctly but it doesn't work.

Comment: now change "{% static '../../../images/logo.png' %}" to "{% static 'images/logo.png' %}"

Comment: It still doesn't work. When I click on "Show image" I get an information: Page not found (404) ; Request Method: GET ; Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/images/logo.png ; Raiser by: django.views.static.serve ; 'images\logo.png' could not be found.

Comment: can you upload your settings.py file? our edit your question and show me your view.py, template.html, settings.py(static settings)

Comment: I wrote a new comment with code of this three files.

Comment: create a static directory in your project folder and cut image folder in to them you can remove this line ==> '/var/www/static/', in your static dir settings

Comment: Well it finally worked. Thank you a lot for helping me with this problem! You're great!

Comment: your welcome if you read django doc you can solve this type of problems ,add answer check for ending this question